# preg_match not working when I send POST with some fields empty

Tags: php, regex

#### I have following code to match `preg_match` function to make post clean.###

```
foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match("~^[\r\n\s\w\d /<>:,.?@;-]+$~", $value)) {
        echo 'Correct';
    } else {
        echo 'Incorrect';
    }
}
```

#### I have an POST array in PHP, where some fields may be blank/empty. When I leave some fields blank it gives an error literally here says incorrect instead of accepting. I want them to pass through `preg_match` even some fields are empty.

#### I do have following as `print_r` of POST where some fields are empty

```
Array {
    [email] => mi@mi2.com
    [facebook] => 
    [twitter] => 
    [gplus] => glus
    [firstname] => mi2
}
```

Comment: I would use `preg_grep()` instead of a loop. Also change the quantifier from one or more times `+` to zero or more times `*`. Also, there's some redundancy in your expression, you could simplify it to `~^[\s\w/<>:,.?@;-]*$~`

Answer (score 0):

```
<urregex>|(^$)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oO8zI4/1

Comment: Can you make is simple, its my `preg_match` gives negative values when I pass some POST field as empty.